# Confusion over the correct private key

Tags: ssl-certificate, private-key

I inherited work on a website and I am trying ultimately to replace SHA-1 certificates with SHA-2 certificates.

The first step would be to generate a CSR from my server using the command

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key myexistingprivate.key -out newcsr.csr
```

I need to find where the existing private key is. In the root folder there are `.key` files for the `domain.com.key`, `www_domain_com.key` and `star_domain_com.key`. (The site domain on the internet doesn't use www but www is the ServerAlias)

In the `etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl` are the lines

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

In `etc/ssl/private` there is only `ssl-cert-snakeoil.key`

Why would the `default-ssl` reference the snake oil file and not the `domain.com.key` file? How would the domain.com certificate be called? (It's installed correctly)

Comment: I guess there are others then default ssl-site enabled. Have a look in all enabled site configurations in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`. Or `grep SSLCertificate /etc/apache2/* -R`.

Comment: I ran the grep but the only results are default.template and default-ssl

Comment: Anything in the other directories in `/etc/apache2/`?

Comment: No. I also searched in /etc. Weird

Comment: Maybe you have overwritten the snakeoil certificate. Check it with `openssl x509 -in /path/to/cert.crt` -noout -text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found that I just had to update the cloud server's load balancer - in the settings on their intranet site I had to paste in the certificate, private key and intermediate certificate. Now chrome gives me the all clear. I assume that without the load balancer I would have to set up the conf files on the server myself.

There was no ssl configuration on the server files that I see via ssh, which confused me.